# How to use Substring in Linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq, substring

I have this query and I want to retrieve the 2 first character of the address. So I tried this query:

```
    var result = (from c in context.DB_CLIENT
        join ad in context.DB_ADRESSE on c.CLI_ADR_FACTURATION equals ad.ADR_ID
        select new { c.CLI_NOM,ad.ADR_ADRESSE3.Substring(0,2)});
```

But I got this error:

```
Compiler Error CS0746
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the property in the anonymous type a name if you use a method instead of only a property.

```
var result = from c in context.DB_CLIENT
             select new { 
                 c.CLI_NOM,  // property name will be used in the anonymous type
                 ADR_ADRESSE3_Prefix = ad.ADR_ADRESSE3.Substring(0,2)
             });
```

Compiler can't infer the property name when you're assigning the value from expression

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler
>   gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being
>   used to initialize them. You must provide a name for a property that
>   is being initialized with an expression

I presume that `ad` is a local variable or a typo and actually means `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select column using `c.ADR_Address3` and you are selecting through `ad` which is not available. If this in different table than you need to specify that table name

```
var result = (from c in context.DB_CLIENT
select new { c.CLI_NOM,c.ADR_ADRESSE3.Substring(0,2)});
```

Comment: "If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being used to initialize them. You must provide a name for a property that is being initialized with an expression". Your code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `let` keyword to define the short address and use it with the object initializer.

```
 var result = (from c in context.DB_CLIENT
               join ad in context.DB_ADRESSE on c.CLI_ADR_FACTURATION equals ad.ADR_ID
               let address = ad.ADR_ADRESSE3.Substring(0,2)
               select new { CLI_NOM = c.CLI_NOM, Address = address});
```